# Probability to choose at least one green ball and no red balls

Tags: probability

Assume we have $n$ red balls, $n$ green balls, and unknown number of white balls.

We select each ball to a set with probability $p=\frac{1}{n}$ and not choosing it with probability $1-p=1-\frac{1}{n}$ independently with each other.

Show a constant lower bound (does not depend on $n$) on the probability the set will contain at least one green ball and won't contain any red balls.

I've said the probability to choose at least one green ball is $1-(1-p)^n$ , and the probability not to choose any red balls is $(1-p)^n$ .

So the requested probability is $(1-(1-p)^n)(1-p)^n=(1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^n)(1-\frac{1}{n})^n$

How can I find a constant lower bound for this?

Thanks

Comment: Your probabilities for the red and green balls add up to $2$.

Comment: Indeed.  When there are $n$ red, $n$ green, and $m$ white balls, and the selection is unbiased, then you should have $p=1/(2n+m)$ - which is the probability for selecting a particular ball *on the first draw*.  You appear to be drawing more than one, and without replacement.  Also, you have not specified *how many* balls you are selecting.

Comment: @Graham Kemp You select each ball to the set with probability $p=\frac{1}{n}$ and not selecting it with probability $1-p=1-\frac{1}{n}$. The total number of balls your'e choosing is unknown

Comment: @guest If *every* ball has probability $\frac1{n}$ to be chosen then it is impossible that there are more than $n$ balls.

Comment: @drhab Assume you have total of $m$ balls and you want to choose a subset. So you look at each ball and adding it to the set with probability $p$ and not adding it to the set with probability $1-p$.

Comment: Ah. You are making $2n+m$ choices to generate the subsets by including or exclusing each ball in turn. The bias of the inclusion has nothing to do with the number of balls in each group save by coincidence.

Comment: @Graham Kemp Yes

Comment: @guest Understood now.

Comment: When the decisions to select each ball is independent, then the requested probability is indeed $(1-(1-p)^n)(1-p)^n$, which is constant and unffected by the number of white balls.  Asking for a lower bound would make no sense.

Comment: @GrahamKemp You are right. Maybe they aim at an expression without $n$. Hallo guest: Are you familiar with $(1-\frac1n)^n\sim e^{-1}$?

Comment: @drhab Yes it means giving a lower bound does not depend on $n$, and yes I'm familiar with $(1-\frac{1}{n})^n\leq e^{-1}$

Comment: The requested probability takes value $0$ for $n=1$ and takes positive values for $n>1$. So $0$ is the best lower bound you can find in the most general setting where $n$ can take any value in $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @drhab There is a lower bound when $n>1$?

Comment: I have the impression that - if $p(n)$ denotes the requested probability - we have $p(n)<p(n+1)$. If so then $p(m)$ serves as lower bound if $n\geq m$.

Comment: Well, here you are. Two well respected with high reputation were just ahead of me :-).

Comment: @drhab Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct.

The numbers $a_n:=\left(1-{1\over n}\right)^n$ converge monotonically increasing to ${1\over e}<{1\over2}$. This implies that the probabilities
$$p_n:=(1-a_n)a_n\qquad(n\geq2)$$
increase monotonically to the limit ${e-1\over e^2}=0.233$, and one has
$$\min_{n\geq2} p_n=p_2={3\over16}=0.1875\ .$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n$. Then you've found that the desired probability is $x(1-x)$. This has a maximum at $x=\frac12$ and monotonically increases towards that maximum.  As $n\to\infty$, $x$ monotonoically increases towards $\frac1{\mathrm e}\lt\frac12$. Thus the probability monotonically increases with $n$.